# Remove part of a filename

Tags: php

I have filenames that look like this, `DDStub-JON DOE-10-08-22-2017.pdf` . How can I remove everything except the date so that it ends up looking like this,  `08-22-2017.pdf` , recursively? I have around 24 files in around 100 folders.

the directory structure looks like this

```
DDSTUBS
|-- 23
|-- 45
|-- 65
|   |-- DDStub-JON DOE-10-08-22-2017.pdf
|   |-- DDStub-JON DOE-08-08-22-2017.pdf
|   |-- DDStub-JON DOE-07-08-22-2017.pdf
```

Comment: If you don't mind me asking: Why PHP? Are there not enough renaming tools for any operating system?

Comment: @qräbnö - I'll admit to using PHP for system admin type scripting, esp where database access or heavy text manipulation/parsing is required - stuff I would've used perl for 25 years ago.

Comment: @ivanivan: OK, it can make sense, especially when I now see that the required code isn't that long and you may reach your goal faster than getting a program to run and understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Recursive Files Rename**

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(__DIR__));
foreach ($iterator as $file) {
    if ($file->isDir()) continue;
    $path = $file->getPath();
    $fileName = $file->getFilename();
    if($file->getExtension() == 'pdf'){
        $newFilename = substr($fileName, -14);
        rename($path.'/'.$fileName, $path.'/'.$newFilename);
    }
}
```

Read more about [RecursiveIteratorIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php)

**Single Directory Files Rename** 
Make new file each folder and copy below code!

**Code**

```
<?php
//Checking directory for files
$files = scandir(__DIR__);
foreach ($files as $file){
    //Getting file extension, so it won't affect other files.
    $ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if($ext == 'pdf'){
        //getting -17 string from end of file name including file extension.
        $newName = substr($file, -14);
        //renaming file
        rename($file, $newName);
        }
}
?>
```

Run and see the **magic**
It'll rename all file to **date** 
References:
[scandir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php)
[pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)
[substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)
[rename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php)

Comment: I had no idea RecursiveIteratorIterator existed. Bless you @Smartpal!

Comment: @moe It's added since PHP 5.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$files = glob('your/path/../**/*.pdf'); // recursive
foreach( $files as $file ){
    rename( $file, substr($file, -14) )
}
```

Comment: OP want to rename `pdf` not `.php` and substr must be `-17` to get full date.

Comment: @Smartpal thx corrected it :) `08-22-2017.pdf` i count 14 here

Comment: @moe made it recursively

Comment: @Smartpal congrats :)

Comment: Hi, please explain you code, what the glob does, it will greatly improve the quality of the answer, and be more useful for newbies in PHP.